# Query for computing a column using other computed columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

Table: Project Details

```
+-----+------------------+------------+--------------+------------+
| GPN | EmployeePosition | Project.No | ChargedHours | PayPerHour |
+-----+------------------+------------+--------------+------------+
|   2 | B                |        101 |           50 |         57 |
|   3 | C                |        100 |           75 |         44 |
|   4 | D                |        100 |          100 |      24.75 |
|   5 | E                |        103 |          125 |      19.25 |
|   6 | F                |        101 |          150 |         16 |
|   7 | C                |        100 |          175 |         44 |
+-----+------------------+------------+--------------+------------+
```

I need to find out total pay of each Project. So first I have to find out **Total pay per employee** and group it by **Project.No**.

The table below shows the **Total pay per Employee** which is created using other 2 existing columns

```
+-----+-------------+---------+------------+----------+----------------+
| GPN | EmpPosition | Proj.No | ChargedHrs | PayPerHr | TotalPayPerEmp |
+-----+-------------+---------+------------+----------+----------------+
|   2 | B           |     101 |         50 |       57 |         993.75 |
|   3 | C           |     100 |         75 |       44 |           2850 |
|   4 | D           |     100 |        100 |    24.75 |           3300 |     
|   5 | E           |     103 |        125 |    19.25 |        2406.25 |
|   6 | F           |     101 |        150 |       16 |           2400 |    
|   7 | C           |     100 |        175 |       44 |           7700 |
+-----+-------------+---------+------------+----------+----------------+
```

My Query:

```
 Select EngNumber, SUM([CharHrs])[SumOfChargedHours], Levell, CostPH, 
SUM([CharHrs])*CostPH [TotalPayPerEmployee]
FROM data1.dbo.PayedPerHour
GROUP BY EngNumber, Levell, TotalPayPerEmployee, CostPH
ORDER BY EngNumber;

Update data1.dbo.PayedPerHour
SET CostPH = CASE Levell 
                      WHEN 'Associate Director' THEN '79.75' 
                      WHEN 'Senior Manager' THEN '57' 
                      WHEN 'Manager' THEN '44'
                      WHEN 'Senior' THEN '24.75'
                      WHEN 'Staff 2, 3 & 4' THEN '19.25'
                      WHEN 'Staff 1' THEN '16'
                      ELSE 'NULL'
                      END
 WHERE Levell IN('Associate Director', 'Senior Manager','Manager', 'Senior', 
'Staff 2, 3 & 4', 'Staff 1');
```

I want to group the **TotalPayPerEmp** by **Proj.No** but i cant accomplish it.
I would have made silly mistakes in the query since I'm very new to sql so please regret them

Expected table:

```
+---------+--------------------+
| Proj.No | TotalPayPerProject |
+---------+--------------------+
|     100 |           14093.75 |
|     101 |               5250 |
|     103 |            4881.25 |
+---------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Could a WITH CTE help with that? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the selected columns that _are not arguments_ to a set function.

Comment: Please clarify do you want write UPDATE query or just SELECT that returns "Expected table". Why do you enlisted example with UPDATE?

Comment: You can skip directly to the answer by not selecting GPN and EmpPosition.  By selecting those two fields you defeat a `GROUP BY` (for the project) since those fields put the aggregate at Employee grainularity.  Instead select the Proj. No with the other details, do the algorithm as you've indicated, then SUM this algorithm- grouping by Proj. No.

Comment: _"i cant accomplish it"_ Why not? What result did you get, instead of the one you wanted? Was there an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could be done using some of your algorithm, except at the ProjectNo granularity:

```
SELECT ProjectNo
      ,SUM(ChargedHours*PayPerHour) [TotalPayPerProject]
FROM ProjectDetails
GROUP BY ProjectNo
```

This gives output:

```
ProjectNo   TotalPayPerProject
100         13475
101         5250
103         2406.25
```

This is different from your expected output, for some reason.

Here's a SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/21a33/2/0